# Detecting changes in related models in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model in django, let's call it `product`, that is referenced by multiple `purchase` instances.

A purchase can be made for any number of items of the `product`, subject to the following constraint:

The total of all items in all purchases for a given product must be less than a set maximum number of items, which is defined differently for each product.

Users may create a `purchase` for a product, and I want to keep track of the total number of items covered by all purchases at any given time.

This is complicated by the fact that users can modify or delete their `purchase`, thereby changing the total number of items purchased.

How would I go about keeping track of this number for each `product` and updating it every time a `purchase` is changed? Is there a hook that can listen to the purchases for a `product` and detect a change?

`purchase` model:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    items = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
    delivery_method = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    #...
    product = models.ForeignKey('product.Product',
                             related_name='purchases', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`product` model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,)
    items_offered = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=2)
    # Items purchased should be the total number 
    # of items in all purchases for this product... 
    # How do I keep it updated?
    items_purchased = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is override save, delete methods, or use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/):

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    # ... model definition
    def update_items_purchased(self, product):
        purchases = Purchase.objects.filter(product=product)
        if purchases:
            total = purchases.aggregate(total=Sum('items')).get('total', 0)
        else:
            total = 0
        product.items_purchased = total
        product.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Purchase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.update_items_purchased(self.product)


    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Purchase, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        self.update_items_purchased(self.product)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `get('total', 0)` is doing? I'm not familiar with that syntax for field lookups. And would an aggregate statement with `Count` work as well?

Comment: Ah, `get()` is acting on the python dictionary; it's not a queryset `get()`

Comment: sorry it is typo mistake, right way is aggregate, i fixed. About count it is will count rows, and no sum if in items can be any more than 1

Comment: I know the docs say to call `super()` at the end of the new functions, but since `update_items_purchased()` requires an up-to-date count of the `items` in each `purchase`, I have to call `super()` before. I'm making this suggestion in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `post_save` signal.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Purchase)
def update_purchase_amounts(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
     product = Product.objects.get(id=instance.product.id)
     product.items_purchased += instance.items
     product.save(update_fields=['items_purchased'])
```

I'm assuming `purchase.items` is the number of `product` in the `Purchase`.

Though, you may want to do it differently like aggregate all `Purchase.items` fields for the product so that you don't keep updating the amount purchased every time you save a `Purchase` instance. So maybe use something like:

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum
counts = Purchase.objects.filter(product=instance.id).aggregate(Sum('items'))
product.items_purchased = counts
product.save(update_fields=['items_purchased'])
```